# atomic writes and volatile reads

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic, volatile, compare-and-swap

I am designing an multi threaded algorithm in which the requirement is to read the latest value of a shared variable. The writes to the variable are atomic (using compare-and-swap). However, the reads are not atomic.

Consider the following example:

```
//Global variable 
int a = 10;


// Thread T1
void func_1() {
     __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&a, 10, 100);
}

// Thread T2
void func_2() {
     int c = a;
     /* Some Operations */
     int b = a;
     /* Some Operations */
}
```

If the code `int b = a` is executed(by Thread T2) after `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` in func_1(by thread T1), then as per my understanding, it is still not guaranteed to read the latest value of "variable a" as the compiler can cache "a" and use the old value of "a".

Now, to avoid this problem, I declared the variable "volatile" as below:

```
volatile int a = 10;

// Thread T1
void func_1() {
     __sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&a, 10, 100);
}

// Thread T2
void func_2() {
     volatile int c = a;
     /* Some Operations */
     volatile int b = a;
     /* Some Operations */
}
```

For the same scenario of executing `int b = a` by thread T2 after `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` by Thread T1 is finished, is it guaranteed to read the latest value of "a"?

How would cache coherency and memory consistency model affect the volatile read after an atomic write?

Comment: Can you use c++11 and `std::atomic<int>` ?

Comment: Take a look at : http://lxr.oss.org.cn/source/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt

Comment: @Jarod42 Using std::atominc<int> will solve the problem but I am trying to understand what would happen if a volatile read follows a atomic write.

Comment: `volatile int b = a;` is not safer than `int b = a;`. The other thread won't modify `b` (copy of `a`) anyway. The problem may appear in the assignation, and `volatile int a` doesn't solve that (but the problem may appears less often).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On all platforms that you are likely to use that support C++ and multiple threads, reading from a volatile-qualified, aligned `int` will be atomic and will read the latest value. However, it is absolutely not guaranteed by the C++ standard. There may be some platform where it doesn't work, and it might not work with the next CPU, compiler version, or OS version.

Ideally, use something that is guaranteed to provide atomicity and visibility. C++-11 atomic is probably the best choice. Compiler intrinsics would be the next best choice. If you have no choice but to just use `volatile`, I'd suggest you use preprocessor tests to confirm that you're on a platform where it is known to be sufficient and issue an error (with `#error`) if not.

Note that on every platform you are likely to use, CPU memory caches are completely irrelevant because they're made invisible by hardware cache coherence. On all platforms that you are likely to use, the issues are only compiler optimizations, prefetched reads, and posted writes.

Answer (score 3):

The `volatile` keyword only ensures that compiler will not store the variable in a register and instead will load the variable from memory every time it is used. It has nothing to do with the cache or memory consistency models of the system it is running under.

Comment: How about "reading the latest value". Executing `int b = a` after `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap`, will `b` have  value `10 or 100`.

Comment: Also, if the memory is cached, the the volatile variable will read from the cached memory rather than directly going to main memory. So, a volatile read by one thread after an atomic write by another thread, how does other caches see the value.

Comment: It is likely unless your data is being stored in a memory area that requires special management/synchronization between processes/threads.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what is likely here? Seeing the old value or new value?

Comment: It's impossible to answer your questions without knowing more about the system you're talking about. If you're just talking about common CPUs like those in your computer then the hardware/OS handles the cache coherency for you and you don't need to worry about it. For something more complex, the answer could be more complex.

Comment: The underlying system is a common CPU with intel i7/ Xeon processors running on RHEL/Ubuntu/Windows OS.

Comment: @VarunV Caches are made coherent in hardware. Punch "MESI protocol" into your favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` doesn't make read operations atomic. Non-atomic reads concurrent with (atomic) write lead to an undefined behavior. Use atomic read in any form, either `std::atomic` or intrinsics. Don't use `volatile` for any form of concurrency.

Atomic read itself doesn't guarantee that the value will be *latest*. In your case thread T2 may never read 100, in theory. The standard says that implementation (hardware, OS, etc.) should do best effort to make writes visible to other threads in a finite time. Perhaps, it's impossible to put a formal requirements here.

With additional synchronization you can achieve more restricted behavior:

```
std::atomic<int> a = 10;
std::atomic<bool> done = false;

void func_1() {
    int old = 10;
    if (a.compare_exchange_strong(old, 100))
        done.store(true);
}

void func_2() {
    bool is_done = done.load();
    int b = a.load();
    assert(b == 100 || !is_done);

    while (!done.load()); // May spin indefinitely long, but should not do that
    assert(a.load() == 100);
}
```

Actually, to catch that simple atomic read reads not the *latest* value, one would have to put enough synchronization into the program (to define the *latest*) so it will appear working correctly.

Comment: "Atomic read itself doesn't guarantee that the value will be latest." Here I am talking about a very specific interleaving that `volatile int b = a` executes after `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap` . I do agree that if that interleaving does not occur, then we may not see the latest value. Therefore, in this specific interleaving, atomic should work right?

Comment: If you somehow check or enforce _executes after_ (standard uses words _happens after_) between these two operations, then the value read atomically will be whatever was written prior.